# Switching ggplot2 panels around

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

Is there a way to shif the panels of a faced ggplot2 object?

For example, below, it seems `facet_grid()` orders the panels alphabetically. But is it possible for example to switch panels labeled `B` and `C` around as shown below?

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(0)
DATA <- data.frame(
  x=sample(0:1,50,T),
  y=sample(LETTERS[1:3],50,T))

ggplot(DATA)+aes(x=x)+
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(vars(y))
```

[image]